# Conceptual Question: Sequence - Ordered - Individually Accessible Elements container[k]

Tags: python-3.x

This is a question about definitions, not a coding question.

In Python, do sequence and ordered mean the same thing?

Tuples, lists (and strings) are ordered by definition and elements can be accessed via their unique place, container[k]. There are three basic sequence types: lists, tuples, and range objects. Sequence elements (by definition ?) can also be accessed via their unique place in the sequence, i.e. container[k].

Does:   container is ordered  <----> accessible via container[k]

Does:   container is a sequence <----> accessible via container[k]

If both are true:  ordered  <----> sequence

If not:  Which of the relationships above is uni-directional?

Comment: For the 3 built-in classes you mention (list, tuple and range): they are all accessible and keep the order of their elements. Custom (non built-in) classes of containers can implement their iterators any way they like, so in those cases you don't know for sure.

Comment: thanks ralf. So, for built-in classes - are ordered containers sequences and are sequences ordered containers?

Comment: yes; right now I cannot think of any example that does not fit this description